# Intuit Partner Platform - multiple shipping addresses for customer

Tags: php, intuit-partner-platform

I am building an application using IPP (through the php devkit) to get data from customers quickbooks.  I anticipate that many of my users will have multiple shipping addresses in their company files.  Is it possible to get each shipping addresses?

The response I get using the call (using the php devkit)

```
$CustomerService->findAll($Context, $realm, $query, $page, $limit);
```

Seems to only return one shipping address. [This thread](https://idnforums.intuit.com/messageview.aspx?catid=69&threadid=13279&enterthread=y) suggests that multiple shipping addresses is not supported, but perhaps things have changed in the past 2 years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QB 2013 is starting to accept multiple addresses through the SDK.

However, for IPP v2, only the default shipping address will be available.

William Lorfing

Intuit Partner Platform, Developer Relations

Comment: Worth noting that the spec for v3 DOES include support for multiple addresses... though Intuit hasn't really given anyone a good idea of when v3 will actually become available.